# Customizing UITableView to look like UIPickerView

Tags: uitableview, uipickerview

Hi i am a newbie in iOS app development. I have a requirement were in i should have a Picker View that should be displayed in an iPad App. I tried to increase the UIPickerView height but it did not happen after 216 pixel height. I was wondering is there a way to customize UITableView to make it look like a UIPickerView and mimic the whole pickerview functionality. But i got struck in making the tableview scroll like a pickerview.

Is there any way to make the UITableView scroll to function same like UIPickerView scroll.

Please help me out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an other way round instead of customizing UITableView to UIPickerView,.. I used [AFPickerView Framework](https://github.com/arkichek/AFPickerView). That helped me,.!!!